# Why does Firefox lag using NVDA on a page setting textContent?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, screen-readers, nvda

Recently I've been testing my website using screen readers and ran into a page that lags like crazy when using NVDA. More specifically:

- All browser actions are substantially delayed, but NVDA itself runs perfectly fine
- For example, the page normally loads in its entirety in less than a second, but with NVDA active, the first image can take several minutes to render
- Refreshing the page takes several minutes to execute
- Even switching or closing the tab takes several seconds

After some extensive debugging, I isolated the issue into a rather specific set of criteria causing the slowdown:

- This only happens on Firefox (I'm currently on Firefox 90); Chrome and Edge are fine
- This only happens with NVDA; VoiceOver on Mac is fine even on Firefox. I do not have JAWS.
- The action causing a slow down is setting an element's `textContent` on every `requestAnimationFrame`, so it's happening dozens of times per second
- I am uncertain if this is experimentally significant, but I'm running on Windows 10 Home

I managed to **scrape** together a [minimal CodePen example](https://codepen.io/auroratide/pen/VwbzdLr). I used CodePen here because the simplest way I could replicate the issue was by refreshing the page. In the example is a refresh button that activates a spinner, so if the page is fast the spinner will show up for only a brief moment; if it's slow then you'll get to observe the spinner in all its glory.

What I see when I try to refresh:

[image: Attempting to refresh causes an infinite spinner]

So while I isolated *what* is causing the issue, I have no idea *why* this is happening and hence how to solve my original page's problem without deactivating the widget outright.

- What might be the underlying cause(s) of Firefox/NVDA slowing down on a page setting `textContent`?
- Is there an alternative to setting `textContent` that I can or perhaps should consider?
- Is this perhaps an issue that should be filed directly with either Firefox, NVDA, or both?

Thank you!

---

Addendum:

- [NVDA Github Issue](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/12185): This open issue indicates long pages are slow to load, which may be related to my problem
- [My Website's Page](https://auroratide.com/posts/the-bounce-of-rubber-juggle): The page on my website I'm talking about

Comment: Not sure if it's the textContent.  I use firefox most of the time and use NVDA for testing and occasionally I notice a page that takes a long time to load when NVDA is running.  For example, https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes.  In chrome, with nvda running, it's still pretty quick.  In firefox, it's slow.  So there's definitely a firefox/nvda combination.  I don't think that page load is doing anything with textContent.

Comment: Right, I had seen an issue indicating that particularly long pages load slowly (linked in an edit above), but felt my issue was different since the example is not long, just highly dynamic. Potentially both issues are tied to something more fundamental at the firefox/nvda boundary, so I'm glad you brought it up.